# want to update a value in mysql database using variable

Tags: mysql, shell

in a shell program, i am storing a database value in a variable called "app" using below command.

```
app=$(mysql -uroot -p123456 -e 'SELECT applicant FROM `leave` where status="Applied" and applying_date= curdate() order by applying_date' comviva|tail -1);
```

now i want to update a field using this app value.

```
mysql -uroot -p123456 -e 'update `leave` set status="pending" where applicant=$app' comviva;
```

but it is not working. can you please suggest what is the wrong.

Comment: check how quotes work in the shell - and never make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a very bad idea, and should never be used in production code**:

```
mysql -uroot -p123456 -e "update leave set status=\"pending\" where applicant=\"$app\"" comviva
```

1. If you don't know what the value will be, you *need* to escape it, or Bobby Tables will ruin your day.
2. Escaping MySQL values in Bash is going to be far from trivial. Even [quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) can be an absolute pain.
3. If you need to loop over a list of applicants or receive applicants from shell input, you're *much* better off using a language like Python, Ruby, Java, or pretty much anything *not* a shell script which actually supports **parametric queries**.

Comment: it is showing below error.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'leave set status="pending" where applicant="a"' at line 1

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
mysql -uroot -p123456 -e "update leave set status=\"pending\" where applicant=\"$app\"" comviva;
```

You missed quotes at applicant=$app

Comment: `leave` will now be run as a command inside that string. [Bash quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Comment: i am getting below error..
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set status="pending" where applicant="a"' at line 1